# Need help about choosing the right way to support multiple players to play videos

Tags: .net, asp.net, flash, silverlight, html

I will try to be brief here....

I am working on a project where i need to support multiple players and platforms to play videos.

Major Platforms will be: Windows PC,Mac PC,Apple Devices and Android.

This is the precedence i will be following. First it will check browser support for Silverlight 3 or later then Flash then HTML5. If not any one of them is supported user will be asked to installed Silverlight..

I wanted to know which pattern and strategy i should use in order to support this functionality. Currently i have investigated about some javascript api that can do this detection on client side easily and load the player appropriately.. but as many of browser could be without javascript support so this method will fails to play videos..

Is there any way i can do this detection on server side and inject proper Player HTML on client end?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this question come up a lot when dealing with HTML5 video implementation. The ideal precedence (in your specific case) would be as follows:

HTML5 Video → Fallback to Silverlight → Fallback to Flash

I'm not sure about your use of two fallbacks, as Flash is generally accepted as the best fallback from native video—adding an additional fallback creates unnecessary complexity in my opinion.

Regardless, the HTML5 video delivery is the best possible user experience because it doesn't require the use of Javascript or 3rd party plugins, and would work on almost all of your listed platforms by default (the exception being Internet Explorer, which doesn't have support for HTML5 video yet).

The code would look something like this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- For Safari, Chrome, and mobile devices -->
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> <!-- For newer builds of Firefox, Opera, and Chrome -->
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg"> <!-- Fall back for Firefox, Opera, and Chrome -->

    <!-- Insert code for Flash fallback here. If the browser can't load any of the sources above (Internet Explorer), it will load anything you put down here, including <object> and <embed> tags -->
</video>
```

If you were still intent on adding the Silverlight fallback, you could just insert that in the video tag right above the code for the Flash fallback. It will handle them all in order.

Hope this helps you get moving in the right direction.

Comment: quite helpful reply it is. I just need to clarify about precedence.. Should i lineup object tag for flash and below it i should insert object tag for silverlight and browser will show only one of them??? what if browser supports both silverlight and flash?

Comment: one more thing.. i need to have a low quality version of videos for mobile devices.. how can i switch to low quality video version when a request came from some mobile device????

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Unless bandwidth is an issue, in most instances you won't have to worry about serving up a smaller video for mobile since most iPhone and Android devices are capable of playing back really high quality videos and making them look great. The only limitation I'm aware of is iPhones before iPhone 4 can only play video up to 640px wide. If bandwidth IS a concern, then it would definitely be easier to test for specific platforms as opposed to connection speeds.

Comment: For example, the PHP CSS Browser Selector can be easily altered to include calls for Android, but already has detection support for iPhone and iPod Touch built-in. Check it out here: http://bastian-allgeier.de/css_browser_selector/

Comment: Ya most of mobile device can play HD videos.. but my concern is what if there is no such wifi network available for mobile device and user uses EDGE network to access internet, in this case speed will be a real concern if i'll stream a HD version video on it. But Something like Browser select can help deciding which movie url to use.. i'll check it out soon..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, client doesn't notify server that he has javascript disabled. So, the best you can do is ask them to enable js to play videos.